# WebSockets on Android with socket.io in Android

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io, android-webservice

I am looking to leverage my NodeJS+SocketIO server application with a new Android based client Application. Currently I'm using a okhttp3 for Websockets in Android. but I want to use WebSockets with socket.io.

Has anyone else done this kind of library work against SocketIO with WebSocket. So please assistance me.

Answer (score 7):

Just add the following dependency to your Android `build.gradle` file:

```
compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:x.x.x') { //replace x.x.x by 0.8.3 or newer version
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

It perfectly works against Node.js + Socket.io with **0.8.3** version.

Socket `singleton` class:

```
public class Socket {
    private static final String TAG = Socket.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String SOCKET_URI = "your_domain";
    private static final String SOCKET_PATH = "/your_path";
    private static final String[] TRANSPORTS = {
        "websocket"
    };
    private static io.socket.client.Socket instance;

    /**
     * @return socket instance
     */
    public static io.socket.client.Socket getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            try {
                final IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
                options.path = SOCKET_PATH;
                options.transports = TRANSPORTS;
                instance = IO.socket(SOCKET_URI, options);
            } catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Basic usage, `onConnect` event:

```
Socket socket = Socket.getInstance();

private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        //Socket on connect callback
    }
};
socket.on("connect", onConnect);
socket.connect();
```

For more info, visit developer Github [page](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java).

Comment: Hello @AlexTa, but have you any example for WebSocket with socket.io in Android? Thanks.

Comment: @SumitPansuriya I have update my answer, hope it helps

Comment: @SumitPansuriya have you tried this answer? does it work?? I'm getting connection error!